# Give a css block a special id to be recoginzed by

Tags: javascript, css

Is there any way that i can make my css blocks have some kind of id. I want to make my javascript's if else statement able to see which of my css3 media query that is currently activated. So instead of doing something like: `if(document.getElementById("div1").style.fontSize == '1px')` i'd like to give my css block some kind of unnecessary value that does nothing to the text but will make my javascript able to identify which block of code it's from.

Comment: Try this article?  http://zerosixthree.se/detecting-media-queries-with-javascript/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really unclear what you are really looking for. Maybe you want to save in a custom data-attribute your desired information?

Your special ID or your unnecessary value can be anything. Nowadays you can select almost everything with JS:

```
// select by ID
var el = document.querySelector("#element");
<span id="element"></span>

// select by className
var el = document.querySelectorAll(".element");
<span class="element"></span>

// select by custom data attribute
var el = document.querySelectorAll("[data-my-custom-attribute]");
<span data-my-custom-attribute="my-custom-info"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(document.getElementById("div1").style.fontSize == '1px')
```

Why are you trying to do this? You understand that even if you did do this, it is not checking **computed style** on the element, it's just checking if a style of `font-size: 1px` was **explicitly** applied to this element...

Preferably you would be assigning styles to the element using classes. In that case, checking if a class is applied is as easy as

```
elt.classList.has('tiny-font')
```

If you want to see if an element matches a particular selector which you know has a CSS rule defined, you can use `matches`:

```
.foo .bar p { font-size: 1px; }

if (elt.matches('.foo .bar p)) { ...
```

If you want to see which media queries would be activated you can use [window.matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia).